# Haskell draw image over image

Tags: haskell, graphics

I want to take two different images (taken from image files, like .png) and draw one over the other several times in different positions. The resulting image should be presented on screen or generate a new image file, whichever is easier. I´ll be taking that new image and drawing on it more with further operations

Is there any Haskell library that allows me to do this?

Comment: Could you be more specific please? Are you getting image files like `.png`? Do you want to output to the screen in a window? Or a pdf or are you using OpenGL? Or do you want to produce an image file? What have you tried already?

Comment: Check out friday and juicypixels on Hackage.

Comment: I added more info

Answer (score 1):

You can use JuicyPixels to do that sort of thing:

```
module Triangles where

import Codec.Picture
import LineGraphics

{-| Parameterize color smoothly as a function of angle -}
colorWheel :: Float -> Colour
colorWheel x = (r, g, b, a)
  where
    r = floor $ (cos x + 1) * (255 / 2)
    g = floor $ (sin x + 1) * (255 / 2)
    b = floor $ (cos (x+(pi/2)) + 1) * (255 / 2)
    a = 255

{-| Draw a triangle centered about the point (x, y) -}
triangle :: Point -> Path
triangle (x, y) =
    [ (x - k, y - k)
    , (x + k, y - k)
    , (x, y + k)
    , (x - k, y - k)
    ]
  where
    size = 30
    k = size / 2

{-|
  Draw 'n' equally-spaced triangles at a radius of 'r' about a center
  point, '(x, y)'.
-}
triangles :: Float -> Radius -> Vector -> Picture
triangles n r (x, y) =
    [ (colorWheel theta, tri theta) | theta <- steps n ]
  where
    tri theta = triangle ((r * cos theta) + x, (r * sin theta) + y)

{-| Interpolate the range [0, 2pi] by 'n' steps -}
steps :: Float -> [Float]
steps n = map (\i -> i * (2*pi/n)) [0 .. n]
```

And we'll use this module of supporting code:

```
module LineGraphics (
    Point, Vector, Line, Path, Picture, Colour, Radius,
    black,
    drawPicture,
) where

import Graphics.Rasterific hiding (Point, Vector, Line, Path, polygon)
import Graphics.Rasterific.Texture
import Codec.Picture

type Radius  = Float
type Point   = (Float, Float)
type Vector  = (Float, Float)
type Line    = (Point, Point)
type Path    = [Point]
type Picture = [(Colour, Path)]
type Colour  = (Int, Int, Int, Int) -- red, green, blue, opacity

black = (0, 0, 0, 255)

drawPicture :: Float -> Picture -> Image PixelRGBA8
drawPicture linewidth picture =
    renderDrawing  800 800 (toColour black) $
        mapM_ renderFn picture
  where
    renderFn (col, path) = withTexture (uniformTexture $ toColour col) (drawPath path)
    drawPath points    = stroke linewidth  JoinRound (CapRound, CapStraight 0) $
        polyline (map (\(x, y) -> V2 x y) points)
    toColour (a,b,c,d) = PixelRGBA8
        (fromIntegral a) (fromIntegral b) (fromIntegral c) (fromIntegral d)
```

And here's what we get:
[image: The rendered image]

Comment: Is there some numerical reason to use `cos (x+(pi/2)) + 1` rather than `1 - sin x`?

Comment: Nope, none other than me forgetting my basic trig ;)